# how to use switch case with variables in php?

Tags: php

I have a great desire to know whether in fact a function swicht,
I can settle a case that receives parameters variables.
Here I show the code.

```
<?php
function devento($diaa,$mess,$ayoo)
{
   $sieven=false;
   $evento="$diaa-$mess-$ayoo";
  //echo $evento;
 switch ($evento)
 {
       for($a=10;$a<=15;$a++)
            {
                for($i=1;$i<=12;$i++)
                {
                    for($j=1;$j<=31;$j++)
                    {
                       //echo  " $j   $i  20$a <br>";  this if it works with the for

                        case $j."-".$i."-20".$a://question?
                        //or
                        case "$j-$i-20$a$ ": //question?
                        //case '1-1-2013': //this if it works without the for

                    }
                }
            }

             $sieven=true;
                        break;


           // case $i.'-'.$j.'-'.$a:    
 }

 return $sieven;
}
```

the for if it works right, and I tried it on a separate php.
php and shows me the error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'for' (T_FOR), expecting case (T_CASE) or default (T_DEFAULT) or '}' in C:\xampp\htdocs

Thank you very much.
I also passionate about programming and what they can contribute gladly will.
Greetings.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Do you know what a switch does?  You might want to take a look at the PHP manual.  http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: It seems you are trying to make a mapping. This is not the way to do that.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're asking if you can use `for` loops to generate the cases inside a `switch` statement. No you cannot; a `switch` statement can only contain `case` and `default` sections.

See [the PHP documentation on `switch`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) for more details.